# How to get dictionary of files from file path (python)

Tags: python, file, dictionary, python-os, python-3.10

I am trying to get a dictionary from a list of file paths. I have found other methods but they do not go deep into it. I have used the code:

```py
# fs is a list of files
directories = {'': set()}

for f in fs:
    splitted = f.split("\\")
    directories[''].add(splitted[0])

    for i in range(len(splitted)):
        if i == len(splitted)-1:
            break

        d = ''
        for j in splitted[0:i+1]:
            d += j + os.path.sep

        d = d[0:-1]

        if not d in directories:
            directories[d] = set()

        directories[d].add(splitted[i+1])
```

fs is:

```py
['C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps\\aydin-browse', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps\\aydin-browse\\main.app', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps\\calculator', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps\\calculator\\main.app', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system\\apps', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system\\apps\\apps.stats', 
'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system\\data', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system\\data\\data.stats', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users\\aydin', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users\\aydin\\data', 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users\\aydin\\data\\password.stats']
```

directories is:

```py
{'': {'C:'}, 'C:': {'aydin-os'}, 'C:\\aydin-os': {'filesystem'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem': {'', 'apps', 'users', 'system'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps': {'aydin-browse', 'calculator'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps\\aydin-browse': {'main.app'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\apps\\calculator': {'main.app'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system': {'data', 'apps'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system\\apps': {'apps.stats'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\system\\data': {'data.stats'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users': {'aydin'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users\\aydin': {'data'}, 'C:\\aydin-os\\filesystem\\users\\aydin\\data': {'password.stats'}}
```

Comment: you're probably looking for features of `pathlib.Path` https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html

Comment: Could you clarify: are you looking for all the files of the current directory? Or all the files in the subfolder as well?

Comment: @ChrisHappy I am also looking for the subdirectories

Comment: What's the issue with your code ?

Comment: @MauriceMeyer it lists them as complete sperate dictionaries: ex: I want {'c:':{'aydinos'},'aydinos': {'filesystem'} to become {'c:':{'aydinos':{'filesystem'}}}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out using defaultdict I could nest the file paths. Code for anyone interested:

```py
# fs is the list of the files
for idx in range(len(fs)):
    fs[idx] = fs[idx].replace('\\','/').replace('C:/aydin-os/','')

for f in fs:
    f2 = f.split('/')
    estring = 'files'
    for f3 in f2:
        if f3 == '':
            continue
        estring += '["' + f3 + '"]'
    estring += ' = {}'
    exec(estring)
```